# command (voice) recognition based project

Tags: java, android, wav, voice, speech-to-text

I am searching for a way to recognised pre-registered **voice commands** in java for a project and i couldn't come up with a good approach yet, I have looked into **fast Fourier** and different ways to treat **wave files** but i can't decide how i should go about implementing it.

the idea is simple, the user will record his/her voice with a short phrase and then when the phrase is repeated the application should recognise which command is issued.

any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice recognition is an unsolved problem that multibillion dollar companies are spending millions and years to solve.  Simply said, if you're only at the FFT level, you aren't going to do it.  Instead, you should be looking for libraries that do it for you.  One is even included in Android-  check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html

Comment: the problem with working with libraries is the fact that it has to be limited to the language that the library is limited to, what i want to do is store any phrase (it could be german or urdu), and this phrase would come from the user, and once its part of the library then he may use it to issue a set command!

Comment: Let me put it this way-  are you willing to spend the next 10-20 years of your life full time on this project?  Because that's the kind of effort being put into professional efforts to turn speech into text.  Once you have a speech to text library making it work with fixed commands is a matter of a few minutes, I've done it a dozen times.

Comment: i could try and edit existing libraries! plus i do believe within the next 10 or 20 years the propriety code for voice to text will be opensourced! ill post back when done with the project but thanks anyway